# How to learn non-technical skills (business & soft skills)?

Tags: project-management, learning, soft-skills

2 years ago, I moved from tech lead in a team of 4 devs at a smallish startup to a big financial company with a completely different landscape (like enterprise IT) and different technology. I'm 55 y.o.

My role should be "technical product manager" -- quite a change. The business is new to me. I thought I understood Agile methodology and all that, but I'm overwhelmed.

I'm supposed to engage stakeholders & business experts and execute projects with remote teams, but I really struggle to have conversations with people. I don't understand what people are speaking about, I can't properly summarize "action items" during meetings, and I can barely defend myself during steering meetings. I'm asked to explain budgets and resources belonging to the enterprise structure, which changed already 2 times. I don't understand or remember people and roles...it's a complex matrix organization.

I see younger people understanding things significantly faster than me and running things and their own projects.

I think I do understand what soft skills are, but I don't know how to "learn" them. I read so many books, but applying things in reality is different and at 55, I don't expect it to be fast.

On the other side, my technical skills are irrelevant as the tech stack is completely different and I'm not used to enterprise architecture.

I'm mostly a self-learner, but here there is no reliable wiki or documentation, most of the things I have to learn by asking the right people at the right moment, as a "favour". Often I don't even understand who I should ask.

I wonder if it's a matter of time (I don't have much) or if some training or mentoring can help, but I don't know where to find it.

Comment: It feels like there's a disconnect between the question title and body: the title says soft skills but at least half the body seems to be talking about organizational/business skills? TPM is a role requiring (IMO) very solid, bordering on "anal" organization skills in addition to the technical chops. It's definitely a lot to keep track of. Is your problem with business arcana or business politics or both?

Comment: A mild overdose of caffeine works for me when trying to keep up with younger people

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You learn these skills the same way you learned your technical ones. Step one: value them and know you need to learn them. You have that covered, which is great. Step two: get things straight in your head. The skills to persuade someone to follow your plan are not the skills to summarize a budget and neither are they the skills to keep track of people and their roles and who they report to. Make a list. What do you need to learn how to do?

Step three: start looking for resources. There are classic books like How to Make Friends and Influence People. There are thousands of blogs, videos and such on highly crisp things like how to remember names or how to make a convincing argument. Choose the format (book, video, short blog etc) that works best for you. Work on learning what you need to learn and monitor how you're doing on that process.

Step four might be to refine your list as you go, adding things or deciding things are "good enough". You should have time for this since you've been in the job 2 years and haven't been either fired or told you need to straighten up and fly right, so while you may feel stressed and flustered, you're apparently managing to get at least some stuff done to an acceptable level. After your training process, you'll be doing even better!

Comment: Charisma on Command is an excellent youtube channel with 10 minute videos, greatly helped me transition into a more leadership oriented position where people were supportive of me.  And +1 for "How to Make Friends and Influence People"